# flutter late initialize error in object detection using flutter tflite from tensorflow

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, machine-learning, tflite

**when i implemented example frok flutter tflite text classification example i got this error when classifying text**

The following LateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
LateInitializationError: Field '_dict@277468318' has not been initialized.

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Classifier._dict (package:tflite_flutter_plugin_example/classifier.dart)
#1      Classifier.tokenizeInputText (package:tflite_flutter_plugin_example/classifier.dart:106:49)
#2      Classifier.classify (package:tflite_flutter_plugin_example/classifier.dart:89:32)
#3      _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:tflite_flutter_plugin_example/main.dart:77:56)
#4      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1154:21)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:654:11)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:311:5)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:244:7)
#9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:630:9)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
#12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:625:13)
#13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
#14     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
#15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:465:19)
#16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:445:22)
#17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:331:11)
#18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:400:7)
#19     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:363:5)
#20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:320:7)
#21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:293:9)
#22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:158:13)
#23     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:382:7)
#24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:31)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#3e095
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(332.0, 488.7)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(19.3, 24.4)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

Comment: Hi@Manan,you're encountering an AttributeError because the tf_datasets module doesn't have an attribute named load. This could be due to several reasons, including version compatibility issues or incorrect usage of the library and Make sure you're using the correct method for loading datasets from TensorFlow Datasets. The correct method might vary depending on the version you're using.
It seems like _dict in your Classifier class has not been initialized when you're trying to access it. To resolve , ensure that you properly initialize _dict before accessing it in your Classifier class.